# Where clause not working with parantheses

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, expression-trees, queryover

Suppose the following Query using a NH 3.4 and RepositoryPattern

```
var list = _repository
     .QueryOver()
     .Where(x => (x.Age > 20))  // notice the parantheses
     .Future()
     .ToList();
```

Whith these parantheses added the NH is failing to work, and causes a SO exception.

If replacing `.Where(x => (x.Age > 20))` with `.Where(x => x.Age > 20)`
it works as expected.

## Any clues on why it doesn't work with extra parantheses?

#### Note

This is a simplified scenario from the bigger picture. In production i'm passing that `.Where(...)` through a parameter `Expression<Func<Person, bool>> where`

Comment: *This code (simplified) is working for me. I am running  NHibernate 4.0.3.4000  and this is not an issue. Could you upgrade?*

Comment: :( My bad. My current version is `3.4.0.4000`. The new 4.0.3.4000 has lot of breaking changes and could cause even more unpleasant surprises at this moment. Any other clues on how to solve this one? Maybe there is a way to remove the parantheses from the Linq Expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a doubt the error is there:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> mc1 = x => (x.ID > 20);
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> mc2 = x => x.ID > 20;

var body1 = mc1.Body.NodeType; // GreatThan
var body2 = mc2.Body.NodeType; // GreatThan
```

The brackets are removed by the compiler. There is nothing in the Expression tree "language" (class system) to explicitly represent a bracket.

Comment: Will have a re'check. Great illustration +

Comment: You were right. It was a caused by the huge amount of data returned depending on the param.