# How to remove Parantheses from System.Linq.Expressions.Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, expression-trees

Suppose the following class defined:

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to build an `Expression` which compares the `Age` property to be Greather than `20`, like this:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "Person");
MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, "Age");
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(20);
Expression exp = Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);
```

Now the `exp` is `(Person.Age > 20)`

Need it to be like `Person.Age > 20`

#### How to remove those parantheses?

Comment: I am using NHibernate, and adding this expression tree with brackets seems to fail, even when written explicitly. While without brackets its OK

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274155/where-clause-not-working-with-parantheses/30274452#30274452 You had already asked nearly the same question with exactly the same response: there are no brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brackets are not really in the tree. This is just the way the built-in `ToString` output works. It is for debugging purposes only. The `ToString` output isn't even C# - it just sometimes looks like it. Try `true || true` to see what I mean. It is formatted as `True OrElse True` I believe.

The output format can't be changed. If you require a certain output format do the formatting yourself. This can be quite a bit of work.